# Request.Server variables blank for classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

We are running a classic ASP app, and the upgrade to IIS 8.5 caused our Request.Server variables to be blank:
AUTH_USER
LOGON_USER

Windows Auth is the default authentication type, and server admin has verified all other options are disabled like Anonymous Authentication

Anything else we should be trying?
I saw this in another forum, but not sure how to use:
Response.Write(User.Identity.Name.ToString())

...the above line with User.Identity breaks our ASP page.

Tried both:
<% WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name %>
<% HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>

...and it breaks the page.

The web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<tracing>
<traceFailedRequests>
<remove path="*.asp" />
<add path="*.asp">
<traceAreas>
<add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
</traceAreas>
<failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500" />
</add>
</traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Neither of those examples is Classic ASP syntax are you sure you're using Classic ASP and not ASP.Net?

Comment: Classic for sure.  Admin told use we're using Windows Auth, so just trying to exhaust all options to prove that.

Comment: None of those options has anything to do with Classic ASP, so rather than exhausting options you're barking up completely the wrong tree. If the `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` is empty it means you are running with anonymous access enabled, check IIS to confirm this isn't the case. Not sure what header you are checking but the correct list of headers can be found here - [IIS Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602%28v%3dvs.90%29).

Comment: If we hit site in private browser tab and no prompt for credentials >> looks like anonymous is still allowed in some way.  IIS anonymous authentication is disabled from screenshot sent by server admin.

Comment: Admin set authentication property on main/root site and that seemed to fix the issue.